# Return True if Date in 1 table is within 24 hours of Date from table 2

Tags: sql, postgresql

I basically want to return a new column, 'First_24?' as shown in the desired output below that will return 'TRUE' IFF the the Folder_ID has a 'FOLDER_DATE_CREATED' within the first 24 hours following the 'TEAM_CREATE_DATE'. My attempt below for some reason yields TRUE for everything?

```
SELECT Folder_ID, 
       TEAM_ID, 
       FOLDER_DATE_CREATED, 
       NAME, 
CASE WHEN t.TEAM_CREATE_DATE <= d.FOLDER_DATE_CREATED + interval '24 hours'
THEN TRUE 
ELSE FALSE END AS First_24?

FROM DATA d
JOIN TEAM t on t.id = d.id
```

**Current data Model**

```
Folder_ID   TEAM_ID FOLDER_DATE_CREATED NAME
11          100     1/21/2021           Sample 1
12          101     1/24/2021           Sample 2
13          102     4/21/2021           Sample 3
14          103     3/11/2021           Sample 4
15          104     5/31/2021           Sample 5
16          104     4/12/2021           Sample 6
        
TEAM_ID Team_Create_Date        
100     1/21/2021       
101     1/24/2021       
102     2/20/2020       
103     3/21/2020       
104     4/12/2021       
104     4/12/2021
```

**Desired Output**

```
Folder_ID   TEAM_ID FOLDER_DATE_CREATED   NAME        First_24?
11          100     1/21/2021           Sample 1        TRUE
12          101     1/24/2021           Sample 2        TRUE
13          102     4/21/2021           Sample 3        FALSE
14          103     3/11/2021           Sample 4        FALSE
15          104     5/31/2021           Sample 5        FALSE
16          104     4/12/2021           Sample 6        TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery with `EXISTS`

```
SELECT d.*, 
       (EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM TEAM t
                WHERE d.FOLDER_DATE_CREATED  >= t.TEAM_CREATE_DATE AND
                      d.FOLDER_DATE_CREATED  < t.TEAM_CREATE_DATE + interval '24 hours'   
               )
       ) AS First_24?
FROM DATA d;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check, if `FOLDER_DATE_CREATED` is less than `TEAM_CREATE_DATE` plus 24 hours. You've added 24 to another side:

> ```
> with f(Folder_ID, TEAM_ID, FOLDER_DATE_CREATED, NAME) as (
>   select *
>   from (values
>     ( 11, 100, date '2021-01-21', 'Sample 1' ),
>     ( 12, 101, date '2021-01-24', 'Sample 2' ),
>     ( 13, 102, date '2021-04-21', 'Sample 3' ),
>     ( 14, 103, date '2021-03-11', 'Sample 4' ),
>     ( 15, 104, date '2021-05-31', 'Sample 5' ),
>     ( 16, 104, date '2021-04-12', 'Sample 6' )
>   ) as t
> )
> , t(TEAM_ID, Team_Create_Date) as (
>   select *
>   from (values
>     ( 100, date '2021-01-21' ),
>     ( 101, date '2021-01-24' ),
>     ( 102, date '2020-02-20' ),
>     ( 103, date '2020-03-21' ),
>     ( 104, date '2021-04-12' )
>   ) as a
> )
> select f.*
>   , cast(
>       f.FOLDER_DATE_CREATED
>         between t.Team_Create_Date
>         and t.Team_Create_Date + interval '24 hours'
>     as varchar(5)) as "First_24?"
> from f
>   join t
>     using(team_id)
> ```
>
> ```
> folder_id | team_id | folder_date_created | name     | First_24?
> --------: | ------: | :------------------ | :------- | :--------
>        11 |     100 | 2021-01-21          | Sample 1 | true     
>        12 |     101 | 2021-01-24          | Sample 2 | true     
>        13 |     102 | 2021-04-21          | Sample 3 | false    
>        14 |     103 | 2021-03-11          | Sample 4 | false    
>        15 |     104 | 2021-05-31          | Sample 5 | false    
>        16 |     104 | 2021-04-12          | Sample 6 | true
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d337dcad4513d9c8c0942946d692411c)*